# What is the most efficient way to convert a split-up date to a datetime value in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm trying to tie together two SQL Server 2005 databases using a view.  The source database splits the date across three int fields.

```
RecordId | RecordYear | RecordMonth | RecordDay
-----------------------------------------------
000001   | 2001       | 1           | 26
000002   | 2002       | 3           | 10
```

My goal is to create an easier-to-work-with view with a single datetime field for the date, something like below.

```
RecordId | RecordDate
---------------------
000001   | 2001/01/26
000002   | 2002/03/10
```

What is the most efficient way to get this done?

Right now, I'm casting each column as a varchar, concatenate them with slash separators, then casting the full varchar as a datetime.  I have to feel like there's a more efficient way.

```
cast(
    cast(RecordYear as varchar) + '/' + 
    cast(RecordMonth as varchar) + '/' + 
    cast(RecordDay as varchar) 
    as datetime
) as RecordDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't cast to string, and [definitely not to `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Try:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
  RecordId    CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
  RecordYear  INT, 
  RecordMonth INT, 
  RecordDay   INT
);

INSERT @x VALUES('000001',2001,1,26);
INSERT @x VALUES('000002',2002,3,10);

SELECT 
  RecordId, 
  RecordDate = DATEADD(DAY, RecordDay-1, 
      DATEADD(MONTH, RecordMonth-1, 
        DATEADD(YEAR, RecordYear-1900, '19000101'
      )))
FROM @x
ORDER BY RecordId;
```

Results:

```
RecordId  RecordDate
--------  ----------
000001    2001-01-26
000002    2002-03-10
```

Comment: This looks far better.  Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: In your last edit, the line `DATEADD(YEAR, RecordYear-1900, 0` was changed to `DATEADD(YEAR, RecordYear-1900, '19000101'`.  Is this more compatible?

Comment: @dangowans well it is definitely more explicit and self-documenting. `0` is shorthand for `1900-01-01` and I'm trying to break myself of all of my shorthand habits.